# About the Jquery's Selector (Nested Element)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to ask if the Jquery Statement `$(selecterA:not(selectorB), elementA)` means that "return those element(s) matching the selectorA but not selectorB within the elementA". Because I am so confused with the following simple case [Fiddle#1](http://jsfiddle.net/kghtp513/). May i know why the both output statements' `.length` will output 0 instead of 2 and 3 respectively?

I then try to remove the div.inner `<div class="child inner">`. It is still 0. And i found that `$('.child', outer).length` is also 0 which should imply that there is no '.child' element within the `outer` element. But why `$('input:not(.child input)', outer)` will exclude those inputs within itself.

Can anyone briefly explain by? Do i have something wrong in concept? Thank in advance.

**Update 1**

For some reasons,  i need to get the number of inputs within its level only (not including its nested children). As the level of the input within its `div.child` can be unknown/dynamic. I cannot simply use `$('> input', outer)` here.

I updated the [Fiddler#3](http://jsfiddle.net/799e5hrL/) to show the problem. The expected results are 2 and 3.

Comment: It would help to understand what is confusing to you if you explain exactly why you think the fiddles should get the results you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Your "outer" `<div>` also has class "child", so every `<input>` inside the outer `<div>` matches `.child input`.

A selector like `.child input` matches any `<input>` that has *any* parent element with class `.child`, not just the direct parent. If you remove the "child" class from the "outer" `<div>`, then the two `<input>` elements that are outside the "inner" `<div>` would not match `.child input`.

Comment: Not work even if i changed to `:not(.child > input)`

Comment: @cubecc oh, right; **all** the `<input>` elements in your example match both `.child input` and `.child > input`, because all of them have an immediate parent with class "child". If you take the "child" class away from the "outer" `<div>`, that should help.

Comment: from your explaination. I am confused why `$('.child input', outer).length` in Fiddle#1 will return 3 (inputs from inner child) but `$('input:not(.child input)', outer).length` return 0. Is the searching area of the selector `:not(.child input)` not only limit within the `outer` element?

Comment: `.child input` matches any `<input>` tag with a parent *at any level above* with class "child". **All** of the `<input>` elements inside your "outer" `<div>` match `.child input` because the outer `<div>` has class "child".

Comment: "All of the <input> elements inside your "outer" <div> match `.child input`..." [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/cxkagmkn/). If yes, it should return 5 instead of 3.